# Как сократить вредный код ?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Помогите натолкнуть меня на мысль, как можно избавиться от такого говнокода ?
Сначала, как правило пишу, а потом рефакторю. Первая мысль была использовать циклы при создании обьектов. Стоит ли их использовать или можно обойтись более изящным способом ?

```
   using System;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Waypoint PlayerSpawnPoint1;
        public Waypoint PlayerSpawnPoint2;
        public Waypoint PlayerSpawnPoint3;

        public Waypoint EnemySpawnPoint1;
        public Waypoint EnemySpawnPoint2;
        public Waypoint EnemySpawnPoint3;

        public UnitAI PlayerUnitPrefab;
        public UnitAI EnemyUnitPrefab;

        private float _time = 15;
        private int _unitNimber = 0;
        private bool _init = false;

        void Start()
        {
            InitGame();
        }

        void Update () {
            if (_init)
            {
                if (_time >= 15)
                {
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint1, 0); 
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint1, 5);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint1, -5);

                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint2, 0);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint2, 5);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint2, -5);

                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint3, 0);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint3, 5);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint3, -5);

                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint1, 0);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint1, 5);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint1, -5);

                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint2, 0);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint2, 5);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint2, -5);

                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint3, 0);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint3, 5);
                    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint3, -5);
                    _time = 0;
                }
                _time += Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        private void InitGame()
        {
            _init = true;
        }
        private void SpawnUnit(UnitAI prefab, Waypoint spawn, int offset)
        {
            try
            {
                var unit =
                    (UnitAI)
                        Instantiate(prefab, spawn.transform.position + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset), spawn.transform.rotation);
                unit.NextWaypoint = spawn;
                unit.GetComponent<Unit>().UnitID = _unitNimber++;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: пора бы нам запустить аналог codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SoloMio, это была бы отлично.

Comment: @SoloMio к сожалению тут вообще давно не было каких-либо нововведений, даже очень нужных.  Почитаешь бывает что-то из вопросов/предложений на Мете, где пользователи предлагают теми или иными способами улучшить Хэшкод, администрация отвечает "мы планируем добавить эту возможность"..и на этом всё заканчивается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

самое первое - вот эту портянку

```
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint1, 0); 
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint1, 5);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint1, -5);

SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint2, 0);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint2, 5);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint2, -5);

SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint3, 0);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint3, 5);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint3, -5);

SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint1, 0);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint1, 5);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint1, -5);

SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint2, 0);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint2, 5);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint2, -5);

SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint3, 0);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint3, 5);
SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, EnemySpawnPoint3, -5);
```

заменил бы на одну функцию и цикл

```
void SpawnUnit3(XXX PlayerUnitPrefab, YYY Enemy) {
    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, Enemy, 0);
    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, Enemy, 5);
    SpawnUnit(PlayerUnitPrefab, Enemy, -5);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    SpawnUnit3(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint1);
    SpawnUnit3(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint2);
    SpawnUnit3(PlayerUnitPrefab, PlayerSpawnPoint3);
}
```

Последний код можно теориетически ещё в один цикл завернуть. Но я не знаю типов, поэтому, приходиться быть осторожным и писать `XXX` и `YYY`.

Comment: Возможно ли у вас проконсультироваться ? у меня есть тестовое задание которое я делаю для работодателя, чтобы устроиться на работу поэтому хотелось бы провести ревью кода чтобы увидеть что у меня там не так и подправить. Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: @Sier дело ваше, конечно, но на работу-то все-таки вас берут, а не @KoVadim, поэтому чужим опытом недостаток своего не заменишь. 

 Я на месте работодателя был бы далеко не в восторге от того, что соискатель в тестовом задании сдает мне нормальный код, я беру его на работу, а потом оказывается, что тестовое задание было "причесано" профессионалом, а сам программист пишет вот такие вот портянки.

Comment: @DreamChild, дело в том что я не прошу за меня писать код, всего лишь подсказать как нужно делать это правильно и это всего лишь прототип, я в любом случае изменил бы данный скрипт т.к, когда есть что то готовое, рефакторить гораздо проще чем писать и сразу же оптимизировать...

Comment: Иногда, лучше походить часок, обдумать и написать нормально.

Я посмотрел на код - там долько копипастить пол часа. То есть, если чувствуете, что копируете (дублируете) много кода - пора выносить в функцию.

Comment: @KoVadim, еще вопросик. Как лучше реализовать движение обьектов ? используя навмеш, A*, или например Antares с кривыми безье для создания сплайнов пути ?

Comment: Я не Ваш работодатель. Я не знаю, как нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim, это не важно. просто интересует, что лучше всего использовать ?

Comment: Это очень важно. Поверьте.